# AngularJS compile dynamic content

Tags: angularjs

Consider the following webpage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<title>First Test</title>
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script>
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
    function addDiv(){
    var div = "<script> \
        myApp.controller('myController', function ($scope) { \
            $scope.testDynamic = function(){ \
                alert('it works!'); \
            } \
        }); \
        <\/script> \
        <div ng-controller=\"testController\">{{\"TEST\"}}<button ng-click=\"testDynamic();\">Click Me!</button></div>";
        $("body").append(div);
        // How to use $compile here???
    }
</script>
<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<div>{{"AngularJS"}}</div>
<button onclick="addDiv();">addDiv</button>
</body>
</html>
```

When the content is appended to the body, how I can load/compile the angularjs part? I have tried to use $compile like:

```
angular.element('body').injector().invoke(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
                            $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                                var scope = angular.element(div).scope();
                                $compile(div)(scope);
                            });
                        });
```

But without any success. I get the error: "Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'scope' is required..."

Someone can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some tries, I got it working. It was simpler than I thought. After the definition of angular module, I need to add this configuration part:

```
myApp.config(['$controllerProvider','$compileProvider', '$filterProvider', '$provide', function($controllerProvider, $compileProvider, $filterProvider, $provide) {
    myApp.register = {
      controller: $controllerProvider.register,
      directive: $compileProvider.directive,
      filter: $filterProvider.register,
      factory: $provide.factory,
      service: $provide.service
    };
```

Then to register the controller coming from ajax:

```
myApp.register.controller('myController', function($scope) {
   $scope.name = "Pippo";
   $scope.age = 18;
   $scope.go = function(){alert('It works!')}
});
```

Then, at the success call from ajax add the compile part:

```
$compile($('#remdiv'))($scope);
```

Here's the complete code:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="myApp">
 <head>
 <title>First Test</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script>
        myApp = angular.module('myApp',[])
  .controller("mainCtrl", function($scope, $http, $compile, $rootScope){
   $scope.addDiv = function(){
   var ajaxhtmlcode = '<script> \
    myApp.register.controller(\'testc\', function($scope) { \
     $scope.name="Pippo"; \
     $scope.age=18; \
     $scope.go = function(){alert(\'It works!\')} \
    }); \
    <\/script> \
    <div id="remdiv" ng-controller="testc"> \
    {{msg}} \
    Name:<input ng-model="name" /> \
    Age:<input ng-model="age" /> \
    <button ng-click="go();">Go!<\/button> \
    <\/div>';
   $('body').append(ajaxhtmlcode); 
   $compile($('#remdiv'))($scope);
   }
  });
  
  myApp.config(['$controllerProvider','$compileProvider', '$filterProvider', '$provide', function($controllerProvider, $compileProvider, $filterProvider, $provide) {
   myApp.register = {
     controller: $controllerProvider.register,
     directive: $compileProvider.directive,
     filter: $filterProvider.register,
     factory: $provide.factory,
     service: $provide.service
   };
  }
  ]);
    </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <div>{{"AngularJS"}}</div>
    <button ng-click="addDiv();">addDiv</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1- First of all you have incorrect controller naming, you inject a controller named `myController` but you trying to call controller named `testController`

2- you can't declare new controller with this way you have to declare it first and inject the template only via `compile` method

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<title>First Test</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>

    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[])
    .controller("mainCtrl",function($compile,$scope,$rootScope){
    $scope.addDiv=function(){
    var div = $compile("<div ng-controller=\"test\">{{\"TEST\"}}<button ng-click=\"testDynamic();\">Click Me!</button></div>")($rootScope);
        $("body").append(div);
        // How to use $compile here???
    }
    
    })
    
       .controller('test', function ($scope) { 
            $scope.testDynamic = function(){ 
                alert('it works!'); 
            } 
        }); 
        
    
</script>
<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
<div>{{"AngularJS"}}</div>
<button ng-click="addDiv();">addDiv</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Peter. The first was a copy-paste mistake. I am new in Angular and I am just trying to understand how it works. Your solution works, but what I wanted to point our is this:
What about if I can't define the controller "test" BEFORE? I mean, if the controller definition comes from a html ajax request (I mean if the div variable is populate by an ajax request, controller definition included). That's why I have put the script definition inside the div variable.

Taking back my example...main page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<title>First Test</title>
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script>
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[])
        .controller("mainCtrl",function($compile,$scope,$rootScope, $http){
            $scope.addDiv=function(){
            $http({
                url: "test.php",
                method: "post",
                data: '',
                responseType: 'text',
                headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                }
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                    $('body').append(response.data);
                }, function errorCallback(response) {
                     alert(response.statusText);
            });
            }
        });
</script>
<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">{{"AngularJS"}}
<button ng-click="addDiv();">addDiv</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Where test.php is simply:

```
<script>
myApp.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
            $scope.name = "Pippo";
            $scope.age = 10;
            });
</script>
<div ng-controller="myController">
Name:<input ng-model="name" />
Age:<input ng-model="age" />
</div>
```

If I run this code, I can't see the input (name and age) populated as defined in "myController"...